# notifyItemRemoved() scrolls the recycler view but does not call onScrolled()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have a recyclerView set up to work as a carousel view. As the items move they expand as they get close to the centre of the screen. The method to scale the views is called by overriding onScrolled(). My problem is when deleting an item the view is scrolled but onScrolled() is not called and the views do not scale. Is there a way to know when a view is removed and the animation is finished?
I can not override onItemRangeRemoved() because that is only called at the start of the delete.

```
 @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            initEmptyView();
            addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    onScrollChanged();
                }
            });
        }

public void onScrollChanged(){
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        int childCenterX = (child.getLeft() + child.getRight()) / 2;
        double spreadFactor = 150;
        float scaleValue = getGaussianScale(childCenterX, 1f, 0.1f, spreadFactor);
        child.setScaleX(scaleValue);
        child.setScaleY(scaleValue);
    }

    int currentPosition = myLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    ((TopUp) context).setCurrentPosition(currentPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
 recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator(){
        @Override
        public void onRemoveFinished(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {
            super.onRemoveFinished(item);

        }
    });
```